# Why does my heir change if I imprison my son(s) in Crusader Kings 2?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

Any time I imprison my non-heir son he automatically becomes heir. Why is that? For example, I uncover a plot by my second son to assassinate me or my heir and after I decide to imprison him (the legal way with no penalties) he goes to jail but also becomes my heir. It is extremely annoying because I don't want to keep executing half my family just to keep my preferred son as heir.

I'm playing as the Duke of Galich. I switched from Gavelkind as soon as I could, so the succession laws are Agnatic-Cognatic Primogeniture.

Comment: What are your succession laws?

Comment: It used to be gavelkind but i changed it to seniority as soon as i could.Females can inherit if there is no son.Im playing as the duchy of Galic (russian)

Comment: Made a slight mistake,I switched to Primogeniture succession law,not Seniority.

Comment: It may well be that something unrelated happened at about the same time to your older son. I suggest check your older son's situation: Firstly, is he still alive? Has he somehow become a bishop? Did he get eunuched (this can happen if you have him steal techs in Byzantium)? There are more possibilities, but basically look for anything that may have changed your older son's heritability.

Comment: That's the catch though,nothing has happened to him.He is alive and healthy ruling as a count.He is not a eunuch either and i have never attempted to steal tech from any country (thus thank you for the tip of the side effect of stealing techs) There are no visible changes in my first born.As i said,if i executed my imprisoned son (the son that somehow became my heir without me wanting to) my first born reverts back to being heir so its not a condition that would permanently disallow him from inheriting.